# Manipulate PDF file and split to several files

Tags: pdf

Daily we create a PDF file, contain all sales invoices, by delivery the order to customer we need to get customer signature. We need a solution to split the PDF file and create different pdf file for each invoice. ( find invoice header and split to new file and save it by invoice No. as name)

I want to know is there any ready to use solution to make such as this tasks on PDF files?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to ask on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/); here requests for software recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: (1.) Questions asking to recommend a tool are off-topic on Stack Overflow. (2.) You don't even mention a programming language. Do you want to do this in Java or .NET? Use iText. Do you want to do this in PHP, Python,... use another tool.

Comment: Why don't you just change the process which creates the PDF so that it creates multiple files?